# editing a textarea value after posting a task on JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, appendchild

im creating a task managment system and created a div which all tasks created by the user will append to right here:

```
</div><div id="ar_notes" class="ar_wrapper">

    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="add_apt" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>


</div>
```

and bootstrap modal that posts tasks right here:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<ul class="rslides">

<textarea id="put_note" autofocus></textarea>
<input onClick="addmore()" data-dismiss="modal" id="add_note" type="submit" value="הוסף משימה">


</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

this is my script that appends my notes on to the wrapping div:

```
    function addmore() {

var newText = $('textarea').val();
$('#ar_notes').append('<br />');
$('#ar_notes').append('<article><div class="note"><p class="show_note">' +newText +'</p><button><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>').fadeIn(500);
$('textarea').filter('[id*=put_note]').val('');


}
```

my question is if i can click on the div of the task and get the modal with the same text in it to edit the task?

thanks!